# SQL row update +1

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm trying to add +1 in custom row. Example:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `MVP` = `MVP` + 1 WHERE `steam_id` = `%s`;
```

But nothing. What's wrong? Syntax looks good i think.

Comment: possible problem in where

Answer (score 1):

%s is a value so remove `

You can usually omit that everywhere unless you are using some "unlucky" column names

```
UPDATE `users` SET `MVP` = `MVP` + 1 WHERE `steam_id` = %s;
```

Comment: It's worth noting, that by "unlucky column names", we mean [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) such as 'update', or 'where' for instance.

Comment: @JustCarty and some terrible punctuation choices

Comment: @Strawberry is that a dig at my terrible punctuation in my comment, or general SQL experience? ;)

Comment: @JustCarty No dig. Although punctuation should never be included in table/column names, backticks allow for it.

Answer (score 0):

Take the ' away from the MVP you are incrementing.

```
UPDATE `users` SET `MVP` = MVP+1 WHERE `steam_id` = `%s`;
```

Comment: Why not remove all backticks then?

Comment: @u_mulder ... fair comment, I was just focussing on the bit in question

Comment: I should have added a caveat which said "If that doesn't work, then there is a problem with the query finding the entity it is trying to update", which @Rok D has correctly spotted, which I didn't

Answer (score 0):

Post the entire code snipped. Can´t really help you like that. What is steam_id? What is %s. When do you replace it with an actual value? You should also just use prepared statements and not DYI that. %s is not how they look like in PDO or MYSQLI, but sure looks like a placeholder for a string.

You also marked this as insert, yet you´re doing an update.

Those ``` `` ``` are kinda unnecessary, never used them for column/table names, but appears to work at least in mysql console.

The sql snipped looks right, assuming MPV is numeric and the id is a string/varchar and equals %s, or you´re replacing it with something.

**EDIT:** As some have said the %s is the problem use nothing if it´s a int. Use single or double quotes if it´s a string. And you don´t need to use anything anywhere else, but if you wish to do so you can.